# SUBIR ARCHIVOS AL SERVIDOR PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de guardar documentos en el servidor, encontre un video en youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qB3X0olSugo .que lo explica pero al parecer esta en una version obsoleta de php. si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria. el codigo funciona hasta que le pincho subir archivo luego de eso no muestra nada. aun me cuesta la programacion estoy aprendiendo hace poco. saludos .

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'])) { 
     
     
      // creamos las variables para subir a la db
        $ruta = "upload/"; 
        $nombrefinal= trim ($_FILES['fichero']['name']); //Eliminamos los espacios en blanco
        $nombrefinal= ereg_replace (" ", "", $nombrefinal);//Sustituye una expresión regular
        $upload= $ruta . $nombrefinal;  

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'], $upload)) { //movemos el archivo a su ubicacion 
                    
                    echo "<b>Upload exitoso!. Datos:</b><br>";  
                    echo "Nombre: <i><a href=\"".$ruta . $nombrefinal."\">".$_FILES['fichero']['name']."</a></i><br>";  
                    echo "Tipo MIME: <i>".$_FILES['fichero']['type']."</i><br>";  
                    echo "Peso: <i>".$_FILES['fichero']['size']." bytes</i><br>";  
                    echo "<br><hr><br>";  
                    
                   $nombre  = $_POST["nombre"]; 
                   $description  = $_POST["description"]; 

                   $query = "INSERT INTO archivos (name, description, ruta, tipo, size) 
    VALUES ('$nombre','$description','".$nombrefinal."','".$_FILES['fichero']['type']."','".$_FILES['fichero']['size']."')"; 

       mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error()); 
       echo "El archivo '".$nombre."' se ha subido con éxito <br>";       
        }  
    }  
 } 
?> 

<body> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    Seleccione archivo: <input name="fichero" type="file" size="150" maxlength="150">  
    <br><br> Nombre: <input name="nombre" type="text" size="70" maxlength="70"> 
    <br><br> Descripcion: <input name="description" type="text" size="100" maxlength="250"> 
    <br><br> 
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBIR ARCHIVO">   
</form>  
</body>
```

Comment: Cambiar la función ereg_replace (obsoleta) por mb_ereg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado si tienes la carpeta "upload" creada? Yo metería otra condición más indicando si existe esa carpeta.

```
if(!file_exists($ruta)){
     mkdir($ruta, 0755) or die("Hubo un error al crear la carpeta");    
}
```

Si quieres seguirlo por pasos... te dejo un post que se explica paso a paso de cómo subirlo:
https://lacodigoteca.com/php/subir-varios-ficheros-a-la-vez/